# Determine $ex(n,P_k)$ for each pair of n and k

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have to find the maximum number of edges in $P_k$ free graph where $P_k$ is path of length $k$.

> I know the result that a graph on $n$ vertices with no path of length $k$ has edges$\ \le 1/2(k-1)n$. But how to determine for each pair.

Comment: The standard meaning of $P_k$-free is, that the graph may not have an *induced* $P_k$.
So $K_n$ does not have an induced $P_3$ no matter how large you take $n$.
Your bound would imply that $K_n$ has at most $\frac 12(3-1)n=n$ edges. Which is false.

Comment: But why specifically 3? I want to know for each pair of n and k

Comment: I did not provide a solution, just an indication that you might have misinterpreted the problem: if a graph is $P_k$-free, it still may have a paths of length much larger than $k$. Another misinterpretation may concern $P_k$ itself: in standard terminology, $P_k$ is a path of length $k-1$.